# Is it true that $f' \le 0$ for almost everywhere in (0,1) imply $f$ is monotone decreasing in (0,1)?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function satisfying $f' \le 0$ for a.e. in $(0,1).$

> (1) Is it true that the function $f$ is continuous and/or monotone decreasing in $I$?
>
> (2) If we give an additional condition $f' \in L^1(0,1),$ what properties for $f$ do we get?

I would be grateful if you give any comments for my questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $f'$ a weak derivative, or an a.e. pointwise derivative?

Comment: @CalvinKhor It is pointwise derivative.

Comment: well, then the example of Viktor shows you don't get either of the two properties even if $f'\in L^1$

Comment: @CalvinKhor You are right. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @CalvinKhor How about the weak derivative case?

Comment: You should ask a new question

Comment: @CalvinKhor I asked a new question. See [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3205422/what-properties-do-we-have-for-weak-derivative-f-satisfying-f-le0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first condition need not be true:
Consider
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
-x, & \text{if } x \in \left(0, \frac{1}{2}\right), \\
\frac{1}{2} - x, & \text{if } x \in \left[\frac{1}{2}, 1\right).
\end{cases}
$$
Then, $f'(x) = -1 \le 0$ almost everywhere in $(0,1)$, but $f$ is neither continuous (in $\frac{1}{2}$) nor decreasing on $I$.

As @CalvinKhor mentioned in the comments, because the Lebesgue integral "doesn't see null set" (i.e a single point $x = \frac{1}{2}$), we also have $f' \in L^1(0,1)$, so we don't get any other properties with that condition.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An interesting example is [Cantor's singular function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).
It is **continuous**, satisfies $f'(x) = 0$ almost everywhere, but is not monotone decreasing.  In fact it is increasing.