# What properties do we have for weak derivative $f'$ satisfying $f' \le0$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function with a weak derivative $f'$ satisfying $f' \le 0$ in $(0,1).$ We may give an additional assumption $f' \in L^1(0,1).$

From this, what properties can we know for the function $f$? For example, the monotonicity of $f$, etc.

I would be grateful if you give any comments for my questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Include a link to the notion "weak derivative".  By saying $f' \in L_1(0,1)$, do you assert that the weak derivative $f'$ is a genuine function (and not a more general distribution)?  By saying $f' \le 0$ do you assert $f'$ is at worst a measure (and not a more general distribution)?